# Save number of root nodes in GXT Tree during tree reordering

Tags: java, gxt

Usage version of GXT is 3.0.0

How it is possible prevent dropping of any nodes on root level ?
In my tree I have, let say, 3 root nodes and I allow reordering inside, but I have to keep only 3 nodes as a Roots. Feedback is set to BOTH(insert+append) and there is possible to drop into leafs nodes.

regards, 
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, what I found is overload handleInsert or handleAppend methods of TreeDropTarget class in proper way.